# MoveFirst works on first call, fails on second

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I am creating an Access 2007 database, which contains two tables (Applicants and Opportunities) and a link table (Applicants-Opportunities). I am populating these tables from a flat file in another table using VBA. The code for checking whether a record already exists in the link table is

```
szSQL = "((([Applicants-Opportunities].[User Id])=""" 
         & rsInc![User Id] & """) 
       AND (([Applicants-Opportunities].[Opportunity Id])=""" 
           & rsInc![Opportunity Id] & """))"" 

rsLnk.FindFirst szSQL
```

The first time through, with all three tables blank, this code works. The second time, I get a 3070 error saying that the system doesn't recognise "Applicants-Opportunities.User Id" as a valid field name.

I'm at a complete loss. If it worked the first time, why not the second? Neither Id in the second case is the same as in the first.

Answer (score 0):

.FindFirst method change current position to first found record and change property .NoMatch to False. If nothing found .NoMatch is true.
If you need search another records you can use .FindNext method with checking .NoMatch property.
You can read about in [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194787.aspx) from msdn. There is example.

But, you might use sql for your target. Something like this:

```
UPDATE [Applicants-Opportunities] INNER JOIN [another table] 
ON [Applicants-Opportunities].[User Id] = [another table].[User Id]
AND [Applicants-Opportunities].[Opportunity Id] = [another table].[Opportunity Id]
SET [Applicants-Opportunities].[SomeField] = 'SomeValue'
WHERE [Applicants-Opportunities].[SomeOtherField] = 'SomeOtherValue'
```

sorry for my english)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and the link. So if NoMatch is true I need to reset the file pointer. Makes sense!

Comment: I guess, yes. If rsLnk.NoMatch = false then >> {populate tables or what you doing} >> rs.Lnk.MoveFirst >> rsLnk.FindFirst... If not a secret, what is the structure of the files? Csv?